# Plancherel theorem of fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to show [Plancherel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Properties): If $(c_n)\in l^2(\Bbb Z)$, there exists a unique function $f \in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\hat{f}(n)=c_n$.

I saw a proof goes like this: $f_k=\sum_{|n| \le k}c_ne^{inx}$ is a cauchy sequence in $L^2$, so converges to limit $f\in L^2$, and you can check that $\hat{f}(n)=c_n$.

But how about defining $f=\sum c_n e^{inx}$? Isn't it true that $f\in L^2$ and $\hat{f}(n)=c_n$?

Comment: Since $f_k \rightarrow f$, I don't see how the two statements differ from one another.

Comment: But how can you prove that $f_k \to f$ in $L^2$ sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we define $f$ as a series, we actually write that $f$ is the limit of partial sums. But limit in which sense? $L^2$? Almost everywhere?

Here, using orthogonality, one can show that 
$$\lVert f_{m+n}-f_n\rVert_{L^2}^2=\sum_{j=n+1}^{m+n}|c_j|^2,$$
which gives Cauchyness.